# Is it possible to run mac osx apps on a X11 server?

Tags: macos, xorg, x11-forwarding

I can successfully open a `ssh -X` connection from `host.home` to `host.work` (both Mac OS X).
X11 is running on `host.home`. When I start `xterm` or `xeyes` on `host.work` I see it on `host.home`, but if I start macvim it runs on `host.work`, not in `host.home`.

Is it possible to remotely use macvim on `host.home`, or can only X11-enabled programs be used for remote interaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, only X11 programs can be used remotely. Mac OS X native apps use a completely different toolkit. From this in the [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23387):

> The Mac OS X native application do not use the X protocol for the rendering, but the Mac specific protocol. So you cannot use ssh X protocol forwarding as you could with a Linux workstation.

As a (not as good) solution you could use VNC.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS apps don't use the X protocol.  But the *de facto* standard for remote GUI interaction is [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), which OS X supports natively.  Enable Screen Sharing under System Preferences -> Sharing and you can use a VNC client running locally under X11 to interact with the GUI on the remote Macintosh.

Comment: I know. But the problem is that with slow connections, the replication of the entire desktop through VNC is frustating. Do you know if the vnc server can use, for instance, fmwm2, or any other lightweight windoe manager?